# Перенос строки SPAN title='txt'+&#13;&#10;+'txt2' через Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Есть отрывок из Javascript функции:

> `var spanA = document.createElement("span");
> cell.appendChild(spanA);
> spanA.innerHTML = "5";
> spanA.setAttribute("class", "five");
> spanA.setAttribute("title", commentA+"&#13;&#10;"+title);`

Что нужно сделать, чтобы вместо символов `&#13;&#10;` происходил перенос строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spanA.setAttribute("title", commentA+"\n"+title);
```